# How to get all days of a week (starts from Monday) till current-day (today)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code, but It gives me the wrong answer:

```
SELECT * from TABLE
WHERE endDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND   endDate <= CURDATE();
```

let's say the week starts from Monday, and today is Wednesday, I would like to list columns with `endDate` of today till last Monday (Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday) .

But the above query gives last Saturday till Monday OR in

```
WHERE endDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND   endDate >= CURDATE();
```

gives Tuesday till end of the Week, 
BUT I want Monday (First day of the week) till Wednesday (Today)

Comment: This question has exactly nothing to do with Java, and exactly everything to do with SQL. Please add SQL tag and remove Java tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me.

SELECT ColumnName
FROM TableName 
WHERE  ColumnName >= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY)
AND ColumnName <= CURDATE()

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at the attached image hope this helps.

[This returns dates from the Monday till the current day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8coa.png)

Comment: Thank you for your post :), It helped me, I used it and figured out this query give me the right answer.
SELECT ColumnName
FROM TableName 
WHERE  ColumnName >= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY)
AND ColumnName <= CURDATE()